# Prononciation e

Tags: usage, prononciation, littérature, liaisons, poésie

Bonjour, est-ce que l'on prononce le [e] si le mot est au pluriel ?
Exemples : Murmures éphémères (5 syllabes) ou MurmurEs éphémères (6 syllabes) ?
Je pense qu'on le prononce mais j'ai un doute...

Merci !

Comment: Il faut un peu de contexte STP.  S'agit-il de la littérature ou du quotidien ?

Answer (score 2):

En poésie, on prononcera /myʁ.my.ʁə.ze.fe.mɛʁ/

En prose, /myʁ.myʁ.ze.fe.mɛʁ/ ou /myʁ.myʁ.e.fe.mɛʁ/